# Is there any way to create index exemptions in (Go) code for Cloud Firestore?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

The GoDoc doesn't seem to support this feature.
https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore

I only want to index very few fields, and it's tedious to manually add index exemptions across multiple environments.

Is there anyway to do this in a more automated fashion?
Will this feature be added to the Go API in the future?

I know this might come to Terraform in the future (https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/3305).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not yet supported in the Go client, but support for the Cloud Firestore Admin API was recently added to the Node.js and Java client libraries:

- [updateField for single-field indexes, Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.2.x/v1.FirestoreAdminClient#updateField)
- [FirestoreAdminClient in Java](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/index.html?com/google/cloud/firestore/package-summary.html)

I suspect they will add this feature to the Go client library soon, but I encourage you to also [open a feature request for the Go client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/new).

You can also manage your indexes using the gcloud CLI: [gcloud beta firestore indexes fields update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/firestore/indexes/fields/update)